# How to update a send SendLog extension with a Query Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'm trying to update a SendLog data extension with a Query Activity, but I can't.

My DE has these fields:

```
JobID, ListID, BatchID, SubID, TriggeredSendID, ErrorCode, UniqueID, SentEventDate, OpenEventDate
```

(The UniqueID, SentEventDate are custom fields)

Now, I want to update the SentEventDate & OpenEventDate field with EventDate of SentEvent & OpenEvent objects, so how should I to write the query in a Query Activity to achieve this intent?

And the criteria is:

```
DE.BatchID = SentEvent.BatchID AND 
DE.BatchID = OpenEvent.BatchID AND 
DE.SubID = SentEvent.SubscriberKey AND 
DE.SubID = OpenEvent.SubscriberKey
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to append data to the SendLog via a query activity by setting the update type to **Append**.  But, you cannot perform an update query on the SendLog data extension.  **Update** queries require a primary key on the target Data Extension.  The Sendlog-templated data extensions do not have primary keys.

Generally speaking, the Sendlog is used by the SFMC platform to capture subscriber level details at the time-of-send.  It is most often used as a source in query activities, rather than a target.

Comment: Thank you both. I had set a primary key in my Sendlog, and can update one field one time. I`m now trying to update multiple fields one time.

Comment: I would not recommend adding a primary key to the SendLog.  This SendLog acts as a transaction log of every email send.  By adding a primary key to this data extension you run the risk of a key violation error, which may have unexpected affects.